# Changing Video Properties Loaded by an Image Map

Tags: javascript, html, image, dictionary, video

I've constructed an image map with HTML and have made it so that when clicking the correct area on the map, a video will open in a new tab and autoplay:

(within the body of the HTML)

```
<div>
    <map name="lightmap">
        <area alt="Light Bulb" title="Light Bulb" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'newwindow', 'width=960, height=540'); return false;" href="videos/loop1.m4v" target="_blank" coords="306,768,95" shape="circle" style="outline:none">
    </map>
</div>
<div class="background_img_glow">
    <img src="images/backgrounds/background1.jpg" alt="Man Holding Light Bulb" style="width:100%;height:100%;" usemap="#lightmap">
</div>
```

The only problem is that I can't seem to adjust any of the video properties when it opens in the new window. I'd like to loop the video and, if I can, remove all of the player controls. Any advice would be appreciated.